# Bintray plugin does not pick up the artefact version

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, bintray, maven-publish

I am trying to deploy my artefacts to Bintray with the official [Gradle plugin](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin). Contrary to my expectations, the plugin does not use the version which is set in the build.gradle, but autogenerates a random version string like this:

```
myproject-build_ewroptgflyd6opkee3goj0l63$_run_closure10$_closure30@3afaa4d9.jar
myproject-build_ewroptgflyd6opkee3goj0l63$_run_closure10$_closure30@3afaa4d9-javadoc.jar
myproject-build_ewroptgflyd6opkee3goj0l63$_run_closure10$_closure30@3afaa4d9-sources.jar
```

My build.gradle looks like this. I compared my configuration with several configurations online, but did not find any discrepancies.

```
plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.8.0"
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.1'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.9
    targetCompatibility = 1.9
}

/****************************************
 * Single library "fat-jar" containing all sub projects and 3rd party dependencies
 ****************************************/
configurations {
    childJars
}

dependencies {
    subprojects.each {
        childJars project(it.path)
    }
}

jar {
    dependsOn configurations.childJars
    exclude('**/logback.xml')
    from { configurations.childJars.collect { zipTree(it) } }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}

/****************************************
 * Bintray deployment (needed for Maven Central)
 ****************************************/
bintray {
    user = System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER') // bintray username (not organisation)
    key = System.getenv('BINTRAY_KEY')   // api-key
    override = true

    publications = ['MavenCustom']
    pkg {
        repo = 'my-repository'
        name = 'my-package'
        userOrg = 'my-organisation'
        licenses = ['AGPL-V3']
        websiteUrl = 'https://github.com/myproject'
        issueTrackerUrl = 'https://github.com/myproject/issues'
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/myproject.git'
    }
    version {
        name = project.version
        released = new Date()
    }
}

// Create the pom configuration:
def pomConfig = {
    licenses {
        license {
            name 'GNU AFFERO GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE, Version 3.0'
            url 'https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.txt'
            distribution 'repo'
        }
    }
    developers {
        developer {
            id 'developer-id'
            name 'developer-name'
            email 'developer@me'
        }
    }

    scm {
        url 'https://github.com/myproject'
        connection 'https://git@github.com/myproject.git'
        developerConnection 'scm:git:https://github.com/myproject.git'
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        MavenCustom(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
            artifact javadocJar {
                classifier "javadoc"
            }
            groupId project.group
            artifactId project.name
            version project.version
            pom.withXml {
                def root = asNode()
                root.appendNode('description', 'descr')
                root.appendNode('name', 'Project Name')
                root.appendNode('url', 'https://github.com/myproject')
                root.children().last() + pomConfig
            }
        }
    }
}

model {
    tasks.generatePomFileForMavenCustomPublication {
        destination = file("$buildDir/libs/pom.xml")
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I can force that the generated artefacts use the given version, if I apply  "baseName project.name" and "version project.version" to the jar, sourcesJar, and javaDocJar. However the bintrayUpload task of the Gradle Plugin still uses the cryptic autogenerated version.

Comment: It appears that if I just leave the "mandatory" version section away (from the bintray closure), everything works as expected..

Comment: I run into a similar situation, in the end I took the novoda plugin for publishing my artifacts